# How do I add 2nd IP to /etc/hosts file using Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have a Vm with 2 network interfaces, eth0 and ens10.

So currently I use this:

```
- name: Add IP address of all hosts to all hosts
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/hosts
    regexp: '.*{{ item }}$'
    line: "{{ hostvars[item].ansible_host }} {{item}}"
    state: present
  when: hostvars[item].ansible_host is defined
  with_items: "{{ groups.all }}"
```

But this only adds the IP of the hosts as specified in the Ansible file (this is eth0 interafce).

I want to add the ens10 interface IP to the hosts file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to add the ens10 interface IP to the hosts file.

You can get the address of interface `ens10` using the variable `ansible_ens10.ipv4.address` (assuming you have fact gathering enabled). However, for what you're doing, it might make more sense to use `ansible_all_ipv4_addresses` instead, which would allow you to do something like this:

```yaml
# Ensure we collect facts from all hosts
- hosts: all

# Generate entries in /etc/hosts file
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - blockinfile:
        path: /etc/hosts
        marker: "{mark} {{ item }}"
        block: |
          {% for addr in hostvars[item].ansible_all_ipv4_addresses %}
          {{ addr }} {{ item }}
          {% endfor %}
      loop: "{{ groups.all }}"
```

This could get you entries in `/etc/hosts` that look something like:

```
# BEGIN hostA
192.168.1.1 hostA
100.64.0.1 hostA
# END hostA
# BEGIN hostB
192.168.1.2 hostA
# END hostB
```

(Assuming that hostA has two addresses, `192.168.1.1` and `100.64.0.1`, and hostB has one address, `192.168.1.2`.)

If you don't want `ansible_all_ipv4_addresses`, you could limit the loop to specific interface names:

```yaml
- hosts: all

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - blockinfile:
        path: /etc/hosts
        marker: "{mark} {{ item }}"
        block: |
          {% for iface in ['ens9', 'ens10'] if iface in hostvars[item].ansible_interfaces %}
          {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_%s' % iface].ipv4.address }} {{ item }} {{ item }}-{{iface}}
          {% endfor %}
      loop: "{{ groups.all }}"
```